# Calculus - How to disprove one function greater than another?

Tags: calculus

I have the below inequality which I know is not true. 
A, B, and x are all within (0, 1) and B > A. If I replace values for A, B, and x, the inequality doesn't hold. But I am not able to prove it (or in other words, disprove it).

$$\frac{e^{xB}}{e^{xA}} \gt \frac{xA-1}{xB-1}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that

$$\frac{e^{xB}}{e^{xA}} \gt \frac{xA-1}{xB-1}\iff xB-xA >\log(1-xA)-\log(1-xB)$$

$$\iff \log(1-xB)+xB>\log(1-xA)+xA$$

which is false, indeed

$$f(y)=\log(1-y)+y\implies f'(y)=\frac{-1}{1-y}+1=\frac{-y}{1-y}<0 \quad y\in(0,1)$$

Answer (score 1):

So you need (the values in parantheses are now positive)

$$
{e^{xB}}(1-xB) \le  {e^{xA}}(1-xA)
$$

Since $B>A$, you want that $
f(q) = {e^{xq}}(1-xq)$ is decreasing with $q$. The derivative is

$
f'(q) = -x^2q \; {e^{xq}}$

and this is clearly negative for $x,q \in (0,1)$. That's it.